# Using AsyncTask to call GET, POST methods of a server connection class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, get, httpurlconnection

I am working on an android project, where there is a need to connect to the server via a URL and send and get messages. These methods are in a class called Server Connection. Now I need to call these methods in the main activity but obviously we cannot do network operations on the main thread. So my question is how can I use the AsyncTask to do this, when I have several separates methods within a Server Connection class. The code snippets are provided below.

Server Connection class:

```
public class ServerConnection implements Connection{

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();



    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    // public ServerConnection() {
    //     getMessages();
    // }

    @Override
    /**
     *  gets a set of Messages in form of an ArrayList and pushs it to the Server
     */
    public void shareMessage(ArrayList<Message> messages){
        this.messages = messages;
        jsonObject = jsonParser.parseMessagetoJSON(messages);
        //JSONArray share = new JSONArray();
        //share.put(jsonObject);
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection client = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("URL goes here");
            client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            client.setRequestMethod("POST");
            client.connect();
            Log.d("MSG", "Connection Successful");
            client.setRequestProperty("Key","Value");
            client.setDoOutput(true);
            client.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                .......
                .......
}
}

    //requests the server for Messages and shares them with the Messanger

    public void getMessages(){
        try{
        URL obj = new URL("URL goes in here");
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();
            .......
            .......

}
}
}
```

There is similarly another get method that gets more data from the server. Now I need to call them somehow. How can this be done Using AsyncTask or is there an easier way to go.

Comment: I suggest looking into Volley, should make your life easier

Comment: I think you can use Volley to handle the request response efficiently. Another thing async task is irrespective of Activity life cycle. So it may make several runtime issues.

Comment: why dnt you try retrofit. its superb and 7 times faster then http call

Comment: What is the problem with using AsyncTasks?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend use awesome libraries: Reftrofit 2, OkHttp 3, Gson. They make handle REST api pretty simple, without boilerplate code which you have to write using standard Android classes.

See below for small proof of concept how to use these libraries for your case.

At first make sure that you have permissions and dependencies included to the project:

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
...
```

### build.gradle

```
...

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0-RC1'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
}
```

Next create your adapter with WS method

### RestAdapter.java

```
public interface RestAdapter {

    @POST("/shareMessage/{id}/")
    Call<Void> shareMessage(@Path("id") String id, @Body ArrayList<Message> messages);
}
```

Most interesting things are here. We create RestAdapter which support http communication and ExecutorService to call function from our adapter in background. ExecutorService is better than AsyncTask in this case because can be reused.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final ExecutorService executorService;
    private static final RestAdapter restAdapter;

    static {
        mExecutorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl("https://foo.com/v1/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        restAdapter = retrofit.create(RestAdapter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        shareMessage();
    }

    public void shareMessage() {
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    restAdapter.shareMessage("1", new ArrayList<Message>()).execute().body();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Sources: [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), [OkHttp](http://OkHttp)